# How can I create multiple columns from one condition using withColumns in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'd like to create multiple columns in a pyspark dataframe with one condition (adding more later).

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
df.withColumns(F.when(F.col('age') < 6, {'new_c1': F.least(F.col('c1'), F.col('c2')), 
                                  'new_c2': F.least(F.col('c1'), F.col('c3')),
                                  'new_c3': F.least(F.col('c1'), F.col('c4'))}))
```

In English, when age < 6, create three new columns based on the minimum value of other columns.

Does `withColumns` take `when()` and `otherwise()` as `withColumn` does? The documentation doesn't say.

I suppose I could separate these into individual statements but I hoped I could do it in one shot. Do I need a UDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it looks a bit ugly to repeat the condition, you could try the following (this should be more performant than a `udf`):

```
condition = (F.col('age') < 6)

df.withColumns({
    'new_c1': F.when(condition, F.least(F.col('c1'), F.col('c2'))),
    'new_c2': F.when(condition, F.least(F.col('c1'), F.col('c3'))),
    'new_c3': F.when(condition, F.least(F.col('c1'), F.col('c4'))), 
})

+---+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+
|age| c1| c2| c3| c4|new_c1|new_c2|new_c3|
+---+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+
|  5|  1|  2|  3|  4|     1|     1|     1|
|  5|  4|  5|  6|  7|     4|     4|     4|
|  7|  1|  2|  3|  4|  null|  null|  null|
+---+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumns.html), the `withColumns` function takes as input *"a dict of column name and Column. Currently, only single map is supported*". In your case, you pass the dictionary inside of a when function, which is not supported and thus does not yield the dictionary expected by `withColumns`. To avoid repeating the condition three times and be a bit generic, you can augment all the values of your dictionary with your condition like this:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(3, 1, 2, 3, 4), (10, 9, 8, 7, 6)], ['age', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'])
d = {'new_c1': F.least(F.col('c1'), F.col('c2')), 
     'new_c2': F.least(F.col('c1'), F.col('c3')),
     'new_c3': F.least(F.col('c1'), F.col('c4'))}
df.withColumns(dict([(k, F.when(F.col('age') < 6, d[k])) for k in d])).show()
```

```
+---+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+
|age| c1| c2| c3| c4|new_c1|new_c2|new_c3|
+---+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+
|  3|  1|  2|  3|  4|     1|     1|     1|
| 10|  9|  8|  7|  6|  null|  null|  null|
+---+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+
```

Or a different approach, simply starting from the list of columns you are comparing `c1` to:

```py
cols = ['c2', 'c3', 'c4']
col_list = [('new_' + c, F.when(F.col("age")<6, F.least(F.col('c1'), F.col(c)))) for c in cols ]
df.withColumns(dict(col_list)).show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try this way using `dataframe api's`:

```
df.withColumns({'new_c1':when(col("age")<6, least(col("c1"),col("c2"))).otherwise(col("age")),'new_c2':when(col("age")<6, least(col("c1"),col("c3"))).otherwise(col("age"))})
```

**`Using expr:`**

```
df.withColumns({'new_c1':expr("""if(age <6,least(c1,c2),age)"""),'new_c2':expr("""if(age <6,least(c1,c3),age)""")})
```